# Recommended starting guide on CICD

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cicd, build-pipeline

I'm new to the community, and I looked around a bit but didn't find a good point to start from. I have a specific problem I want to solve, but while trying to think of a solution I realized I need a better devops background, and I couldn't find a resource to help me with that.

So, I'll lay out my specific question, and after that I'll summarize what are the main areas of knowledge I'm hoping to get a better understanding on...

I have a CI pipeline that works something like this:

1. Developer: push code to source control (bitbucket server)
2. Jenkins: poll SCM and run pipeline
3. Jenkins pipeline: build artifacts from code, set environment, and test (pytest)
4. Upon success and demand - manually pack the artifacts into a release

Now, most of the things here are done without any dedicated tools.

e.g.

1. python wheels are created but not stored anywhere (though I do have a dockerized `pypi` server - I just don't have an automated flow that uploads and updates the wheels there)
2. I want to have more artifacts, e.g. `deb`s, binaries, libraries, etc. (I now have them stored inside local storage) and I want them better stored, better sorted and maintained, and more accessible (thought of Jfrog artifactory here)
3. I want the entire environment creation to be handled by proper tools (called from the Jenkins pipeline?), and not scripts I've written (thought of `tox` for creating the python environment, but it's not enough, as I also need to be able to create docker environments, and I also need to control `dpkg` as I have `deb`s I create and install. Maybe `chef` or `ansible` can do the trick. [I do use `ansible` from time to time to configure all hosts on my network, but that's basically for silly things like changing a few config files here and there])

My general question is - is there a guidebook for how to create a proper CICD system, that would be able to at least point me in the right direction? Some of the problems I encounter I fix manually, and I'm sure there are a lot of best practices and best tools for the job I'm missing out of ignorance...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to have a complete guide about CI/CD I think is not possible.. there is too much about processes, tools and customizations. Also the changes are fast and it should be updated every month.

The short answer is:
I have recently performed a complete CI/CD process in an enterprise environment using some of what you just told:

- devs pushing on gitlab (java, react) using gitflow plugin
- jenkins pipelines for every app automatically starts for dev environment doing unit tests, static code tests (sonarqube), integration tests (postman/soapui), updating artifacts on Nexus (mvn), and the pushing the deployment artifacts on the ArgoCD repo.
- ArgoCD manages then the K8S cluster resources

Long answer:
I use a few books as basic referrals, then I follow some youtube channel and I read specific articles to keep me updated.

I'll try to make here a starter list:

**Version Control**

- https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
- https://dzone.com/storage/assets/14796507-dzone-refcard-339-gitops-essentials-2021.pdf
- https://about.gitlab.com/resources/ebook-version-control-best-practices/

**CI**

- https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#understand-build-context
- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/pipeline-best-practices/
- https://geekflare.com/kubernetes-security-scanner/

**CD**

- https://www.gspann.com/resources/blogs/continuous-delivery-for-kubernetes-with-gitops-and-argo-cd/

**Ops**

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tech_talks/getting-started-with-managed-kubernetes-day-2-operations

**Youtube channels**

- https://www.youtube.com/c/DevOpsToolkit
- https://www.youtube.com/c/Digitalocean
- https://www.youtube.com/c/Devopsdotcom
- https://www.youtube.com/c/Rawkode
- https://www.youtube.com/c/KodeKloud
- https://www.youtube.com/c/MarcelDempers

**Books**

- Practical Guide to Continuous Delivery
- [The Goal: A Process of Ongoing Improvement](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/113934.The_Goal)
- Production Kubernetes: Building Successful Application Platforms

I hope this can helps

Answer (score 1):

Of course the information is endless, so I'll give you just one link to a series I found to be very good to [combine the high level with the practice](https://codefresh.io/devops/enterprise-ci-cd-best-practices-part-1/).

Note 2 things though:

- Reading a book usually gives you a more ordered understanding. Starting with one of the foundational is a good point. Like the ones mentioned here.
- There are several approaches around git to choose from: gitFlow, GitHub Flow, GitLab flow, Trunk based development. You need to "sew" the best for the specific team.